# How to split the screen in 3 horizontal divs

Tags: html, css

I'm coding a website and i want to split a page in 3 different section:
one for the title+a button,
one for the content,
one for the text input.

[image: example].

The problem is that the divs don't fill the height and the width of the screen. The second div also need a scrollbar because of his content that can vary.

I'd like to resolve the problem with CSS, but everything is accepted

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Server Messaggistica</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="width:100vh; height: 100vh;">//container of the 3 divs
    <div style="width:100%; height: 15%;">//div1
      <h1>Bentornato utente</h1>
      <a href = "logout.php"><button class=button>LOG OUT</button></a>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div style="width:100%; height: 70%; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">//div2
      //php content
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div style="width:100%; height: 15%;">//div3
      <textarea name="messaggio" rows="3" cols="100"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In general, don't use `height: 100vh;` but min-height (Overwise on average site you get overflow issues). Also no meaning for 100vw her (Div is block element by default). Useful article (If your issue related to "sticky" to bottom footer): https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [`vh` unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh) in CSS, which allows you to specify the height of containers in relation to the height of the viewport.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.vh-15 {
  min-height: 15vh;
}
.vh-70 {
  min-height: 70vh;
}

/* for illustration */
.bg-red   { background: red;   }
.bg-green { background: green; }
.bg-blue  { background: blue;  }
div       { color: white;      }
```

```html
<div class='vh-15 bg-red'>   1: 15% </div>
<div class='vh-70 bg-green'> 2: 70% </div>
<div class='vh-15 bg-blue'>  3: 15% </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this using flexbox. The flex children values are relative to each other. I've based mine out of 100. The numbers are arbitrary though. Instead of 70 and 15, you could use 700 and 150.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  flex: 15;
}

.middle {
  flex: 70;
}

/****************** 
  Presentational
******************/

.middle { background-color: green; }
.middle::after { content: '2: 70%'; }
.top { background-color: red; }
.top::after { content: '1: 15%'; }
.bottom { background-color: blue; }
.bottom::after { content: '3: 15%'; }
.container > div { position: relative; }
body { margin: 0; }
.container > div::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>  
</div>
```